# jQuery validation: Checking if form is validated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to run a function if my form has **completely validated** according to my defined rules (Not shown below).

The below code doesn't work as I would like it to, most certainly depending on the fact that the `success` function is called on a per-input basis and not globally for the complete form .

Are there any workarounds to get a global success callback that runs when the **complete form validates properly**?

```
$("#myForm").validate({

    success: function(label) {

        if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
            runMyFunction();
        }

    },

    rules: {
        //...
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this modification to the validation plugin:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/suggestion-for-validate-plugin

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your answer to make it fully self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myForm").validate({

    rules: {
        //...
    },
    success: function(label) {           

    },
   submitHandler: function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          runMyFunction();           
    }    
 });
```

REF: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

you **dont** have to do

```
if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
            runMyFunction();
        }
```

the `success` callback is called only when the from is validated just `runMyFunction()`

Comment: `success` callback doesn't work on a global basis and is called for every passed validation, ie. for every properly inputted form by the user.

Answer (score -1):

you can you use mass validate of livevalidation

please checkout their api , it has mass validator that does what you exactly want.

http://livevalidation.com/

http://livevalidation.com/documentation#LiveValidationMassValidate

you can also use jquery bassistance validation
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid

Comment: Hi! As you can see in my example, I already call the `valid` function in the success callback. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: you can see @3nigma's answer.. It seems valid.. :)

Comment: Answer makes no sense... OP is asking about jQuery Validate plugin by Bassistance.

Comment: doesn't seem so from the question

Comment: Title says _"jQuery validation:"_, question is tagged [`[jquery-validate]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-validate), and code contains `.validate()`. All three things ==> [Bassistance Validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation).

Comment: I missed the tag description.. but validation is too generic and `jquery validation` refers to a jquery plugin for validation could have been anything `.validate` is also available in livevalidation